# How to remove a file from git branch

Tags: git, github, repository

I committed, but not pushed to repository, a file to a branch i.e. `abc`. Now I want to remove it from this branch `abc`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to obliterate the file from history, as if it never existed. If you just want to get rid of the file in future commits, then use `git rm my-bad-file.txt` and ignore the rest of my answer.

---

If the file is only in your most recent commit, then it's easiest to use `git rm my-bad-file.txt` to remove the file, then `git commit --amend` to edit the previous commit.

If there are several commits containing the offending file, then [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) might be useful.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch my-bad-file.txt' master..abc
```

This means:

- **`git filter-branch`**: Let's rewrite some commits!
- **`--index-filter`**: Change each commit's index without actually checking it out on disk.
- **`'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch my-bad-file.txt'`**: For each commit, unstage the file named "my-bad-file.txt" if it exists.
- **`master..abc`**: Do this on all commits on branch abc back to where it forked from the master branch.

Comment: I did this which removed my file now. Now I want these changes to be merged back to the HEAD. Can you help how can I do that?

Comment: @al0neevenings: There's nothing special after this. Do the normal `git checkout master`, `git merge`. If you have a question about that, please ask it as a new question.